# "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier"

Tags: c++, file, class, syntax, linker-errors

I have a **link.h** file and a **link.cpp** file. When I set up the constructor definition in link.cpp for class Link, I get two errors:

- When hovering the cursor over `Link` in link.cpp, I get ***this declaration has no storage class or type specifier.***
- When hovering the cursor over the `::` after `Link` in link.cpp, I get ***expected a ;*** .

This is a pretty bare bones implementation -- I've double checked the syntax and so far have spotted no structural inconsistencies or syntactical errors. What could this error mean?

**link.h**

```
#ifndef LINK_H
#define LINK_H

#pragma once

class Link
{
public:
    Link();
};

#endif
```

**link.cpp**

```
#include "link.h"

Link::Link()
{
    
}
```

I have other files with different filenames and class names with the exact same structure and syntax as above, but they aren't giving the errors this one is giving me.

Comment: Methinks the link.h you're including isn't the one you think it is., or at least not the one your intellisense processing thinks it is. If this fails to compile with the same error(s), a well-placed temporary `#error Whoopsee` inside the include guard of your header will tell you straight out whether `link.cpp` is pulling in your intended header or not.

Comment: _"When hovering the cursor over ... "_ - but did you try to compile it? Intellisense or similiar tools can have hickups or take some time to find definitions.